# How to detect curves on GPS tracks?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I'm working on a hobby project and I'm trying some algorithms on gps tracks.

I have data containing GPS coordinates(latitude, longitude) of a moving user and I'm trying to detect curves in his path. What would be a good approach for this type of problem? Would it make sense to try a curve fit or hough transform on the data?

Comment: One approach could be to fit a linear model on the last few points. If the track is straight, the error would be low. On curved path, the model won't fit well and the error will be high.

Comment: Spline interpolation is a keyword here. Could you show your examplary data and what kind of curves you need? What is the ultimate goal? Surely the curve detection algorithm must adapt to it. Without knowing it the question is indeed ill-posed.