# How to detect curves and straight paths using GPS coordinates?

Tags: python, pandas, gis

I'm working on a project involving railway tracks and I'm trying to find an algorithm that could detect curves(left/right) or straight lines based on time-series GPS coordinates.

The data contains latitude, longitude, and altitude values along with many different sensor readings of a vehicle in a specific range of time.

Example dataframe of a curve looks as follows:

```
   latitude longitude altitude
1  43.46724 -5.823470    145.0
2  43.46726 -5.823653    145.2
3  43.46728 -5.823837    145.4
4  43.46730 -5.824022    145.6
5  43.46730 -5.824022    145.6
6  43.46734 -5.824394    146.0
7  43.46738 -5.824768    146.3
8  43.46738 -5.824768    146.3
9  43.46742 -5.825146    146.7
10 43.46742 -5.825146    146.7
11 43.46746 -5.825527    147.1
12 43.46746 -5.825527    147.1
13 43.46750 -5.825910    147.3
14 43.46751 -5.826103    147.4
15 43.46753 -5.826295    147.6
16 43.46753 -5.826489    147.8
17 43.46753 -5.826685    148.1
18 43.46753 -5.826878    148.2
19 43.46752 -5.827073    148.4
20 43.46750 -5.827266    148.6
21 43.46748 -5.827458    148.9
22 43.46744 -5.827650    149.2
23 43.46741 -5.827839    149.5
24 43.46736 -5.828029    149.7
25 43.46731 -5.828212    150.1
26 43.46726 -5.828393    150.4
27 43.46720 -5.828572    150.5
28 43.46713 -5.828746    150.8
29 43.46706 -5.828914    151.0
30 43.46698 -5.829078    151.2
31 43.46690 -5.829237    151.4
32 43.46681 -5.829392    151.6
33 43.46671 -5.829540    151.8
34 43.46661 -5.829680    152.0
35 43.46650 -5.829816    152.2
36 43.46639 -5.829945    152.4
37 43.46628 -5.830066    152.4
38 43.46616 -5.830180    152.4
39 43.46604 -5.830287    152.5
40 43.46591 -5.830384    152.6
41 43.46579 -5.830472    152.8
42 43.46566 -5.830552    152.9
43 43.46552 -5.830623    153.2
44 43.46539 -5.830687    153.4
45 43.46526 -5.830745    153.6
46 43.46512 -5.830795    153.8
47 43.46499 -5.830838    153.9
48 43.46485 -5.830871    153.9
49 43.46471 -5.830895    154.0
50 43.46458 -5.830911    154.2
51 43.46445 -5.830919    154.3
52 43.46432 -5.830914    154.7
53 43.46418 -5.830896    155.1
54 43.46406 -5.830874    155.6
55 43.46393 -5.830842    155.9
56 43.46381 -5.830803    156.0
57 43.46368 -5.830755    155.5
58 43.46356 -5.830700    155.3
59 43.46332 -5.830575    155.1
```

I've found out about spline interpolation on this [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28737294/how-to-detect-curves-on-gps-tracks) asking the same question and decided to apply it in my problem:

```
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline

## read csv file with pandas
df = pd.read_csv("Curvas/Curva_2.csv")
   
# take latitude and longitude columns
df['latitude'].fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
df['longitude'].fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)

# plot the data
# df.plot(x='longitude', y='latitude', style='o')
# plt.show()

# using longitude and latitude data, use spline interpolation to create a new curve
x = df['longitude']
y = df['latitude']
xnew = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), x.shape[0])

ynew = make_interp_spline(xnew, y)(x)
plt.plot(xnew, ynew, zorder=2)
plt.show()

## Error results using different coordinates/routes
## Curve_1 → Left (e = 0.04818886515888465)
## Curve_2 → Left (e = 0.019459215874292113)    
## Straight_1 → Straight (e = 0.03839597167971931)
```

I've calculated the error between the interpolated points and the real ones but I'm not quite sure how to proceed next or what threshold to use to figure out the direction.

[image: Curve Example 2]

Comment: Possibly the gis.stackexchange.com (a sister site of us, link also on top right icon) can help better. The question is about programming, but possibly the gis community knows better the answer (with real GPS data, so with non-precise points).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks for letting me know about that other site! I'll go try my luck over there.